# Customizing Woocommerce New Order email notification based on shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

How can I edit the admin-new-order.php WooCommerce template to send conditionally some custom customer details based on shipping method?

For example *(for New Order email notification)*:

- If the Order Shipping method is **`flat rate`**, I want to add some custom fields information to the customer details.
- If the Order shipping method is NOT **`flat rate`**, I don't want custom fields info to be displayed.

Or maybe there's some snippet that goes in function.php for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in any of this hooks *(tuning the hook priority)*:

- woocommerce_email_order_details
- woocommerce_email_order_meta
- woocommerce_email_customer_details

Here it is an example of hooked code (instead of overriding the template):

```
add_action ('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_email_customer_details', 15, 4);
function custom_email_customer_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){

    // Only for "New Order" email notification
    if ( 'new_order' != $email->id ) return;

    // Only "Flat Rate" Shipping Method
    if ( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate') ){
        $order_id = $order->get_id(); // The Order ID

        // Test output
        echo "<p>Message: The Order ID is $order_id</p>";
        echo '<p>Custom field: '. get_post_meta( $order_id, '_recorded_sales', true ) .'</p>';
    }
}
```

The hook priority here is 15, so it comes after the customer details.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to conditionally remove billing address or shipping address details or both (screenshot - http://prntscr.com/gioday), what hook and array should i use?